# array indexing in lua

Tags: arrays, loops, lua, coronasdk

in displaying an array in lua, it always start with 1, so i used it in my sql query if i am using `select * from ...` as reference of `table.id` . my problem now is what if the sql query of `table.id` will not start with 1, or it will be like `[3,5,6, ...]`?

my code is like this,

```
local data = {}

for row in db:nrows("SELECT song.id as id, song.title as song, artist.name as artist, genre.name as genre, album.title as album FROM song, artist, genre, album WHERE song.artist_id = artist.id AND song.genre_id = genre.id AND song.album_id = album.id AND song.duration = 120.00") do
                        data[row.id] = {}
                        data[row.id].song = row.song
                        data[row.id].artist = row.artist
                        data[row.id].genre = row.genre
                        data[row.id].album = row.album
end
```

so the output of `row.id` is [3,5,6, ..] because i used the `row.id` as the index of the array `data`.

my question is what should i do or use so that the index of array `data` will become like this, [1,2,3,....]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use an index variable:

```
local data = {}
local next = 1

for row in db:nrows("SELECT song.id as id, song.title as song, artist.name as artist, genre.name as genre, album.title as album FROM song, artist, genre, album WHERE song.artist_id = artist.id AND song.genre_id = genre.id AND song.album_id = album.id AND song.duration = 120.00") do
    data[next] = row
    next = next + 1
end
```